# Kelley's topology : A lemma about compactness and finite intersection property

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I want to prove this problem by using the fact that **a topological space is compact iff each net in it has a cluster point**. Additionally, I believe that the **finite intersection property** may be helpful. But I feel it is hard to solve it.

This problem is from John Kelley "General Topology" problem 5.F

I just need hint.
Thanks!

Comment: First, you can assume that the whole situation happens in some compact topological space $X$. Just take some $X ∈ \mathscr{A}$ and restrict to $\{A ∩ X: A ∈ \mathscr{A}\}$ and $U ∩ X$.

Comment: Yes! If we restrict these condition to some compact space X chosen from the family A, I can construct an open cover of X and get a finite open cover. The remaining part of the proof is easy. Thank you very much! @user87690

Comment: I have added the hint as answer, so the question can be marked answered.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can assume that the whole situation happens in some compact topological space $X$. Just take some $X ∈ \mathscr{A}$ and restrict to $\{A ∩ X: A ∈ \mathscr{A}\}$ and $U ∩ X$.